# VSCode not commenting css.liquid lines correctly

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, shopify, liquid

I've been having a problem when trying to comment out a line in a css.liquid file with the VScode shortcut (CTRL+/).

Whenever I do this it puts `{%\s*#` in front of the line and doesn't comment out the code. I tried disabling all extensions but it's not helping. I haven't touched any settings. When I switch to CSS or Liquid it will comment out fine, but Liquid CSS doesn't work.

Does anybody recognize this issue?

===== This ended up being a problem with the extension itself, it has since been fixed!

[image: Commenting in css.liquid file]

Comment: Is there a unique language id for these files?  A language server extension you downloaded?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not sure. How would I go about figuring that out?

Comment: What is the language ID in the lower right corner?  And did you have to download any extension to make Liquid CSS work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this issue has been reported lately: [Incorrect comment blocks in Liquid files with this extension enabled](https://github.com/panoply/vscode-liquid/issues/119).

I see this in the liquid css language configuration file:

```json
  "comments": {
    "lineComment": "{%\\s*#",
    "blockComment": [ "/*", "*/" ]
```

I don't know what the lineComment value is supposed to be but I have never seen a regex value there in other language configuration files - so it may be a mistake.

I built an extension which may be able to help until the language configuration file is fixed: [Custom Language Properties](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.custom-language-syntax).

1. Install it.
2. Run the command `Custom Language Properies: Check for new language extensions`.
3. Make this setting in your `settings.json`:

```
"custom-language-properties": {
  "liquid-css.comments.lineComment": "",
}
```

If this doesn't work immediately, try a reload of vscode.

This basically sets the `lineComment`'s to null and so the `blockComment` will be used instead.  I am not familiar with `Liquid` comment styles so let me know if that is not how line comments are supposed to work.  Demo:

[image: fix liquid css comments]

Comment: @F-H The Liquid extension owner is aware of the problem and indicated a fix would be coming shortly...